# PyQt5 QTableView with QItemSelectionModel and setCursor method populated by Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pyqt5, qtableview, qitemselectionmodel

Wondering if my approach is good. Code works as intended, just want to know if there is a better approach. Want to be able to add this widget to any future project. Is there a better way to make it compatible with future projects? Or are there any other glaring problems with the code?

My 3 requirements for the table:

1. Populate from a Pandas DataFrame.
2. Allow for a specified column to have a selection event.
3. Change mouse pointer to a PointingHandCursor when hovering a cell that is clickable

Thank you for any suggestions!

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QItemSelectionModel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem

class Database123:
    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = None

    def create_engine(self):
        self.engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql://postgres:pass@localhost:5432/db')

    def tbl_list(self, table_name):
        try:
            self.create_engine()
            sql = f"SELECT * FROM {table_name};"
            df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, self.engine)
            return df
        except (sa.exc.OperationalError, sa.exc.DatabaseError) as e:
            print(f"Error accessing the database: {e}")
            return pd.DataFrame()
        finally:
            if self.engine:
                self.engine.dispose()
                self.engine = None

class CellTableModel(QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        
        super(CellTableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(data.columns)

        for row in range(data.shape[0]):
            for col in range(data.shape[1]):
                item = QStandardItem(str(data.iloc[row, col]))
                self.setItem(row, col, item)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI(data)

    def initUI(self, data):
        # Create a table view and set it as central widget
        tableView = QTableView(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(tableView)

        # Create a CellTableModel and set it as the model for the table view
        model = CellTableModel(data)
        tableView.setModel(model)

        # Create a selection model and set it for the table view
        selectionModel = QItemSelectionModel(model)
        tableView.setSelectionModel(selectionModel)

        # Connect the selection changed signal to a custom slot
        selectionModel.selectionChanged.connect(self.selectionChanged)

        # Enable mouse tracking to receive mouse move events
        tableView.setMouseTracking(True)

        # Connect the custom slot to handle mouse move events
        tableView.mouseMoveEvent = self.mouseMoveEvent

        # Set up the main window
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('QTableView with Pandas DataFrame')
        self.show()

    def selectionChanged(self, selected, deselected):
        # Custom slot to handle selection changes
        selected_indexes = selected.indexes()
        for index in selected_indexes:
            # Check if the selected column is 'name'
            if index.column() == data.columns.get_loc('name'):
                print(f"Selected 'name': {index.data()}")

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        # Custom slot to handle mouse move events and change cursor
        index = self.centralWidget().indexAt(event.pos())
        if index.isValid() and index.column() == data.columns.get_loc('name'):
            self.centralWidget().setCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)
        else:
            self.centralWidget().setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create a pandas Data Frame
    list_cell = Database123()
    data = list_cell.tbl_list('cell')

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow(data)

    app.exec_()
    del app
```

I have tried multiple methods. This is the only one I could get to work.

Comment: You should avoid to "monkey patch" event handlers (which, by the way, are not "slots"), and, more importantly, you should not do that with existing handlers of other widgets: all widgets (including QMainWindow) provide `mouseMoveEvent()`, meaning that your attempt to override would be potentially called also when a mouse move event is called for the main window. A more appropriate way to do so is to use a subclass and override `mouseMoveEvent()` in there (or, alternatively, use an event filter). Note that setting another selection model for what you're doing is pointless, use the existing one.